# Change MaskFormatter in JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I´m doing a simple log in application on java where the user input is a **JFormattedTextField** that has a MaskFormatter. What I want to do is where the **JFormattedTextField** loses focus want to delete the MaskFormatter (because i have a "placeholder") and add the MaskFormatter whenever it has the focus again (so the MaskFormatter only applies when the user is actually in the **JFormattedTextField**. The only way i´ve found to add the MaskFormatter is via the constructor. Here is some code:

```
usuario = new JFormattedTextField(new MaskFormatter("########U"));
usuario.addFocusListener(this);
usuario.setBounds(64, 182, 267, 24);
usuario.setBorder(null);
usuario.setText("Introduce tu nombre de usuario");
usuario.setForeground(new Color(204, 204, 204));
usuario.setFont(new Font("Cascadia Code", Font.PLAIN, 11));
contentPane.add(usuario);
```

```
@Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        if (usuario == e.getSource()) {
                        // set MaskFormatter here
            if (usuario.getText().equals("Introduce tu nombre de usuario")) {
                usuario.setText("");
                usuario.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
@Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        if (usuario == e.getSource()) {
                        // remove MaskFormatter here
            if (usuario.getText().equals("")) {
                usuario.setText("Introduce tu nombre de usuario");
                usuario.setForeground(new Color(204, 204, 204));
            }
        }
    }
```

i´ve tried to work around with setFormatterFactory method but i dont know how it works, also couldn´t find anything on the internet

Comment: Why not just leave the `MaskFormatter` on all the time?  There is a `JPasswordField` for passwords.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Answer (score 1):

> i have a "placeholder"

Maybe you can use the [Text Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) which was designed to display "prompt text" in a text field when no text has been entered.

The code doesn't work as is with a JFormattedTextField because the formatted text field appears to add spaces to the Document based on the size of the mask.

In the `checkForPrompt()` method of the above class you can try changing the code to:

```
//if (document.getLength() > 0)
if (component.getText().trim().length() > 0)
```

to see if it works the way you want.

Note the Text Prompt class allows you so specify the prompt color so you don't need to change the foreground of the formatted text field.

Comment: The problem with that class is that it uses the setText method, i can´t use that since i have the maskFormatter. For example: if i want to write "enter your username" but the maskFormatter only allows a 00000000A format, the "placeholder" wont be written

Comment: *The problem with that class is that it uses the setText method* - which is why you should be using the TextPrompt class. That was the first suggestion. Other suggestion deleted.